# displaying loading gif on a form during vba sub execution

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to put an animated loading gif on a form during a long subroutine execution (specifically, sub being fired on a form's button click event), and it turns out to be surprisingly difficult in MS Access.

I already have my gif animation put on the form, linked to ActiveX Web Browser control (call it `loadingGif` in example below). It turns out, that doing simply:

```
Private Sub someButton_Click()
    loadingGif.Visible = True
    '... hard stuff here ...
    loadingGif.Visible = False
End Sub
```

fails because screen doesn't get refreshed during subroutine execution, and so the user never sees the `loadingGif` control. Is there any way to make it visible during single subroutine execution?

Also:

1. I know it is possible to create an animated modal pop-up form instead, but that's not the idea
2. I already also use Hourglass, but icon on a form seems much more appealing

Comment: Try calling `DoEvents`at some point during your [hard stuff here] execution part and see if it makes the GIF move at all.

Comment: @silentsurfer that doesn't work. Calling `DoEvents` will sometimes make the gif visible, sometimes it won't, and in either case it will not be animated